# How can I draw contour on image using coordination data obtained by Firebase MLkit?

Tags: canvas, dart, flutter, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I want to draw contour on image by coordination data which is obtained by Firebase MLkit - face detection function.

This feature gives coordination information of each component in face like below.

```
enum FaceLandmarkType {
  bottomMouth,
  leftCheek,
  leftEar,
  leftEye,
  leftMouth,
  noseBase,
  rightCheek,
  rightEar,
  rightEye,
  rightMouth,
}
```

[image]

When I extract coordination of `bottomMouth` from above image(from google search), it was `636.25,419.41`. Therefore, I'd like to use these information to draw contour of face like below image.

[Image Face contour](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/images/examples/face_contours.svg)
[Video Face contour](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*dLGD7NAWUq6LmatZLeBV8Q.gif)

How can I do in flutter? Is it possible?

Comment: The official plugin for using firebase ml kit for flutter is [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision). After reading the [face_detector.dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/lib/src/face_detector.dart) of the package, it seems that the contour feature wasn't written/supported yet.

Comment: I also looked at [FaceDetector.java](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemlvision/FaceDetector.java) and I didn't see the [FirebaseVisionFaceContour](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceContour) class being imported.

Comment: `"How can I do in flutter? Is it possible?"` - sure: use `CustomPaint`

Comment: @JeromeEscalante I looked for all the documents which are related to, but I couldn't found

Comment: @pskink Coordination system is equivalent to `CustomPaint` to `mlkit`?

Comment: its 2D [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)

Comment: Then, just use `CustomPaint` with that image? Does it works?

Comment: have you read `CustomPaint` documentation? if so, whats unclear?